# Pass continuous colorwell data to second view controller

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I have the following situation:

two ViewControllers each containing a box that is to be colored to a color picked from a color well in ViewController
The colorwell is set as continuous in order to see the changes reflected immediately
I am looking for a way to continuously pass the color well value on to the SecondViewController and on to a callback method that will color a box in the SecondViewController.

I found that the prepareForSegue method is commonly used to pass data between view controllers, this however only occurs once during the transition and not continuously.

Can someone point me out in the right direction? Googled for hours but I got really stuck with this.

Thanks.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSBox!

    @IBOutlet weak var well: NSColorWell!

    @IBAction func well(sender: AnyObject) {
        box.fillColor = well.color
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let second = segue.destinationController as! SecondViewController
        second.representedObject = well.color
    }
}

import Cocoa

class SecondViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSBox!

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        // Note that box.fillColor requires box type to be custom
        box.fillColor = self.representedObject as! NSColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The prepareForSegue method is a chance to create links between two view controllers. It's pretty common for the source view controller to set itself up as the delegate of the destination view controller. It's also possible for the source view controller to save a reference to the destination view controller for future reference.

If you define a protocol with a method like

func colorValueHasChanged(newColor: NSColor)

Then you can use it in the IBAction for your color well to pass information about changes in the color well from one view controller to the other.

Comment: Thank you Duncan. This is the direction I needed :-)